# Make a Visual Studio Code snippet with variable assignment

Tags: regex, vscode-snippets

I'm building a Visual Studio Code snippet. I want to assign my selected uppercase text to a variable or something else:

`${TM_SELECTED_TEXT=${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/(.*)/${1:/upcase}/}}`

If it isn't possible, I would like otherwise to capitalize my selected text in a condition: `SQL:FREE(RECH${${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/(.*)/${1:/upcase}/}:${1}})`

For example, my selected text is `house`.

For the first question, the result give me: `${TM_SELECTED_TEXT=HOUSE}`

For the second question, the result gives me:
`SQL:FREE(RECH${HOUSE:})`

I wanted `SQL:FREE(RECHHOUSE)` or `SQL:FREE(RECH)` with the cursor after `RECH` if there isn't any selected text.

`SQL:FREE(RECH${TM_SELECTED_TEXT:${1}})` works, but I want to capitalize it.

Answer (score 0):

### Updated answer

This is a hacky solution, and is not very clean, but I can't think of a better one.

```
SQL:FREE(RECH
${                         # 
  TM_SELECTED_TEXT/(.+)/   # If some text is selected,
  ${1:/upcase})/           # uppercase it and put it back along with ')',
}                          # 
$0                         # then the cursor.
${                         # Else,
  TM_SELECTED_TEXT/(.*)/   # 
  ${1:? :)}/               # put ')' after the cursor.
}                          #
```

Due to [some issues](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/34368), a conditional branch cannot be empty, even though [the EBNF](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_grammar) says that it can:

> ```
> format ::= ... | '${' int ':?' if ':' else '}' | ...
> if     ::= text
> text   ::= .*
> ```

This means that if `TM_SELECTED_TEXT` presents, we need to add a trailing space, and end up with the following results:

| Before | After | Cursor |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `house` | `SQL:FREE(RECHHOUSE)` | `HOUSE)`| |
| `<empty>` | `SQL:FREE(RECH)` | `RECH`|`)` |

### Original

You were close; just wrap the uppercased `TM_SELECTED_TEXT` in `${0:` `}`so that it will be treated as a [placeholder](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_placeholders):

```
SQL:FREE(RECH
${0:${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/(.*)/${1:/upcase}/}}
)
```

| Before | After | Cursor |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `house` | `SQL:FREE(RECHHOUSE)` | [`HOUSE`] |
| `<empty>` | `SQL:FREE(RECH)` | `RECH`| |

If you want the cursor to always be placed after `TM_SELECTED_TEXT`, put `$0` right after it:

```
SQL:FREE(RECH
${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/(.*)/${1:/upcase}/}$0
)
```

| Before | After | Cursor |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `house` | `SQL:FREE(RECHHOUSE)` | `HOUSE`| |
| `<empty>` | `SQL:FREE(RECH)` | `RECH`| |

Comment: That’s not exactly what I want:
If there is a selected text, it should not put the marker after the "HOUSE" like : SQL:OPEN(RECH${TM_SELECTED_TEXT:${1}}) (it only put the cursor if there is no selected text

Comment: Your are very good, thx. It's almost does what I want at 100%. IDK if this stupid language allows it but : Is it possible to remove  the cursor after "HOUSE) " ? Because I have other lignes bellow and it's ennoying. I have another idea (if it's can be done) : At least, is it possible to set the index if there is no selected text at 1 and if there is, put at 200 for example? I want to put my cursor after HOUSE) at the end (the last) after others tabs

Comment: Other question : is it possible to capitalize in a if condition : ${TM_SELECTED_TEXT(.+)/upcase/(white)|(OTHER)/...  or something like this?

Comment: @floreal Unfortunately, no; the conditional structures (e.g. `${1:?foo:bar}`) only accept plain text.

Comment: Oh :( And do you know about my first question ? To change the index or remove it?

Comment: @floreal Probably no. To set the place of the cursor, you will need to place a so-called "variable" at that place in the snippet. If you want it to be 200 characters away, there is probably no other way than using 200, say, spaces in you snippet. Also, as I said, conditional structures only accept text; there is no way to make `${1:?   $0:${1:/upcase}}` work.